# VSCode copied text from PS has hidden symbol

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, photoshop

Hello when i'm copying text from PSD sometimes it has hidden symbol in front of copied text. With visual studio code i can't see this symbol but when i check browser console i can see it there and it mess up elements so i tried the sublime text editor and i can see there the 'blank' symbol is there  way to show this symbol also in the VSCode ?

here is image blue tags is VSCode, "Pink" tags are sublime  the hidden symbol is [BEL]

[image]

Comment: Does View/Toggle Control Characters make them show?

Comment: Cool, let me know if it works and if so I'll make it into an answer.

Comment: @Mark yes, you was right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try View/Toggle Control Characters to reveal those hidden "characters".  There is a command that you could use to make a custom keybinding:

```
{
  "command": "editor.action.toggleRenderControlCharacter",
  "key": ""
}
```